# Django server can't find the static files

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-settings

We're trying to set up a django server to host a web app made with Bootstrap Studio. When trying to merge the backend code and the web frontend, Django is not being able to find the static css and JS files (which are actually there).

Here's our directory tree:

```
bookalobackend:
    -bookalo:
         +static
              -css
              -bootstrap
              -js
              -fonts
         +templates
    -bookalobackend (main project folder)
```

And here's our settings.py file:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

GEOIP_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'geoip2')
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bookalo',
    'django.contrib.gis'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'bookalobackend.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates').replace('\\', '/'),
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'bookalobackend.wsgi.application'

#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-es'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Here's one of our .html files. We've only modified one of the css paths to test everything out, but it is finding the necessary static files.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Bookalo</title>
    <meta property="og:image" content="assets/img/icono.png">
    <meta name="description" content="Tu sitio web de compra y venta de material escolar de segunda mano. En Bookalo, puedes encontrar material de todas las etapas educativas, incluyendo infantil, primaria, ESO, bachillerato y universidad!">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="401x401" href="assets/img/icono.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="401x401" href="assets/img/icono.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="401x401" href="assets/img/icono.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="401x401" href="assets/img/icono.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="401x401" href="assets/img/icono.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/-Filterable-Cards-.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/Bold-BS4-Animated-Back-To-Top.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/Bootstrap-Tags-Input-1.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/Bootstrap-Tags-Input.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/Contact-FormModal-Contact-Form-with-Google-Map.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/favoritos.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/fileinput.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/MUSA_carousel-extended.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/piexif.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/piexif.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/purify.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/purify.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/Sidebar-Menu.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/slider.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/sortable.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/sortable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/starrating.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Are we doing anything wrong, or do we need to configure something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which URL for this file persists in the rendered html? What error status do you get when opening this URL manually? Does this happen in DEBUG=True or False? Did you run `collectstatic`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using django as [development server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) then, add the following codes in your urls:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Then you should be able to see static files being served through django. But this setup is not recommended for production server.

If you are using NGINX or Apache in production server, [then you can use them to serve static contents as well](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/deployment/). Alternatively, you can also use [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) to serve static files in production.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the by ruddra mentioned addition of the dev-only static import to your urls double check your file structure.

[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files) recommends to namespace static and template files. Your file structure should change to the following:

```
bookalobackend:
    -bookalo:
         +static
              +bookalo
                   -css
                   -bootstrap
                   -js
                   -fonts
         +templates
              +bookalo
                   -your_template_files
    -bookalobackend (main project folder)
```

Of course this would require an change for templates in views:

```
render(request, 'bookalo/template_name.html, context=context)
```

And a change in how you add static files to your templates:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bookalo/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But since there's only one app, we feel like having static at that level, without having an internal folder is better for links.